# Exception signature

Tags: python, python-2.7

What's the signature for `class Exception` in python 2.x?

I wish to subclass it and add arguments of my own, while also correctly invoking `super`.

The following code works:

```
class FooError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg, x):
        super(FooError, self).__init__(msg)
        self.x = x
```

But, is there some documentation or reference?  `pydoc Exception` is not helpful.  Neither is the documentation: [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) or [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html).

Comment: `help(Exception)` in a Python console/IDLE?
To make your own custom exception and have it behave as a normal exception, with a different name, just use class `MyException(Exception): pass`.

Comment: What exactly do you have a problem with? Because your code works nicely. Not really sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The only thing I have to say that might help is that when you print an `Exception` you get its `.message`. So setting that will change how your custom exception is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

What you have there is fine.  Alternately,

```
class FooError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg, x):
        Exception.__init__(self, msg)
        self.x = x
```

as from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance):

> An overriding method in a derived class may in fact want to extend
>   rather than simply replace the base class method of the same name.
>   There is a simple way to call the base class method directly: just
>   call BaseClassName.methodname(self, arguments). This is occasionally
>   useful to clients as well. (Note that this only works if the base
>   class is accessible as BaseClassName in the global scope.)

Answer (score 3):

This part of the Python documentation is not very explicit regarding method signatures, but there are some hints.

Quoting the Python Docs (6. Built-in Exceptions):

> ...Except where mentioned, they have an “associated value” indicating
>   the detailed cause of the error. This may be a string or a tuple
>   containing several items of information...

BaseException states the following:

> args
>
> The tuple of arguments given to the exception constructor.

And Exception:

> Changed in version 2.5: Changed to inherit from BaseException.

The rest of the information can only be found in the sources (I think)

```
static int
BaseException_init(PyBaseExceptionObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds) {
    if (!_PyArg_NoKeywords(Py_TYPE(self)->tp_name, kwds))
        return -1;

    Py_DECREF(self->args);
    self->args = args;
    Py_INCREF(self->args);

    if (PyTuple_GET_SIZE(self->args) == 1) {
        Py_CLEAR(self->message);
        self->message = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(self->args, 0);
        Py_INCREF(self->message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see it allows no keyword arguments. *args* is initialized as a tuple in *new*.

So all in all the signature would be:

```
def __init__ ( self, *args )
```

And inheriting from Exception (without restricting the arguments)

```
class FooError ( Exception ):
    def __init__ ( self, x, *args ):
         Exception.__init__ ( self, *args )
         self.x = x
```

I always call the base class explicitly, I don't like *super*. But this is just a question of style.

Note that your code is correct. You just restrict *Exception* to receive only one argument, while it could handle a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `__init__()` of class **Exception** is like this:

```
def __init__(self, obj):
    # do something
```

But I can't find document in Python's website. This can only be confirmed by reading Python's source code.